# How to set order by condition on sqlite based on where condition?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-order-by

I've following query and list of countries in sqlite db

```
select * from country where name like 'searchString%' or name like '% searchString%'
```

If the searchString is 'in', the result will be like

```
1   British Indian Ocean Territory
2   India
3   Indonesia
```

But I need result of first condition's(like 'searchString%' ) result should be come first like

```
1   India
2   Indonesia
3   British Indian Ocean Territory
```

I need this to be done in single query. Is this possible?

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated RDBMS, if you can remove MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL. Thanks

Comment: I just tagged those because of query of these are mostly same logic. So only tagged that

Comment: Ok some one done that. I added new tags related to question.

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 condition in the `WHERE` clause, and the condition:

```
name LIKE 'in%' DESC
```

in the `ORDER BY` clause will return the countries starting with `'in'` at the top:

```
SELECT * 
FROM country 
WHERE name LIKE '%in%'
ORDER BY name LIKE 'in%' DESC, name
```

Another option is the use of string functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM country 
WHERE name LIKE '%in%'
ORDER BY instr(lower(name), 'in'), name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b58efc79bc2939f7d6af10bb0c99cc7f).
Results:

```
> id | name                          
> -: | :-----------------------------
>  2 | India                         
>  3 | Indonesia                     
>  1 | British Indian Ocean Territory
```